# Is unified-write filter part of windows 10 pro?

Tags: windows, windows-10, uwf

I just heard about unified write filter. Is it available in windows 10 pro in a non-embeded environment? how can I set it up?

Answer (score 2):

#### Is unified-write filter part of windows 10 pro?

No. You need Windows 10 Enterprise.

---

#### Microsoft Windows Embedded Unified Write Filter

> You can use unified write filter (UWF) in your Windows 10 IoT Enterprise or Windows 10 Enterprise device to help protect your physical storage media, including most standard writable storage types that are supported by Windows 10, such as physical hard disks, solid-state drives, internal USB devices, external SATA devices, and so on. You can also use UWF to make read-only media appear to the OS as a writeable volume.

Source [Microsoft-Windows-Embedded-UnifiedWriteFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/windows/hardware/mt270131%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I can say that its actually possible, in the Windows 10 Pro Anniversiary Update, to use UWF. I have tested.

The only "thing" is that the uwfmgr.exe is intentinally crippled (eg, disabled), but if you use the WMI interface, or another uwfmgr.exe, it will work flawlessly. Note that the external uwfmgr.exe does not need to be placed in system32 folder, it can reside anywhere.

To install UWF, press Win+R, type Control, press enter. Then navigate to Programs, and then Enable/Disable windows features. Then scroll down to Device-Lockdown, and check UWF.

[image: DeviceLockDown]

What microsoft means with the Enterprise thing, is that this feature is pre-installed in Enterprise.