# Turn Windows 10 Pro into Thin Client - Unified Write Filter

Tags: windows-10, uwf

Long time reader, first poster.

We use Thin Clients in the company and while they serve a role I have always wondered can we not enable the File Based Write Filter that makes a thin client (device using windows embedded 7 or IoT) so powerful on Windows 10 Pro devices.

The cost of a thin client is roughly the same of that of an entry-mid level device (we currently buy HP MT42 and HP T520) however the specs are much lower than you would find on a full fledged PC/laptop.

So my goal of this project is to find a way to write protect a standard Windows 10 Pro device such that it functions like a thin client. We would need the ability to lock and unlock the device, requiring a reboot to do so.

Here is where I am at:

1. Found [this post](https://superuser.com/a/1119217/241386) and looks like it can be done.

> I can say that its actually possible, in the Windows 10 Pro Anniversary Update, to use UWF. I have tested.
>
> The only "thing" is that the `uwfmgr.exe` is intentinally crippled (e.g. disabled), but if you use the WMI interface, or another `uwfmgr.exe`, it will work flawlessly. Note that the external `uwfmgr.exe` does not need to be placed in system32 folder, it can reside anywhere.
>
> To install UWF, press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type Control, press enter. Then navigate to Programs, and then Enable/Disable Windows features. Then scroll down to Device-Lockdown, and check UWF.

2. I have enabled the feature in Windows 10 pro and even found a `UWFMGR.EXE` file from an IoT device I have and placed it on the Win 10 device.
3. Here is where I'm stuck, the `UWFMGR.EXE` file doesn't do anything when run in CMD or double clicked. Also, I don't see the green/red lock in the taskbar.

I am looking for anyone who know a good deal about Microsoft's Microsoft Windows Embedded Unified Write Filter and how it works.

Comment: Does it show anything when you run "uwfmgr get-config" in CMD?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and after banging my head for days, i solved it by downloading the latest ISO of Windows 10 Enterprise and enabled the feature via below command (Run as Administrator):

```
DISM.exe /Online /enable-Feature /FeatureName:client-UnifiedWriteFilter
```

and all worked fine after that. Otherwise you can refer to this forum [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/35883bfa-c5e0-4e11-8510-2bb16ac43a3b/unified-write-filter-not-working?forum=win10itprogeneral)